# How to change value of one column in a specific record in a table EF MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I have the ID of a record I would like to update, However I would only like to edit just one field in this record.

I would like to change the "Availability" field value in the "Vehicles" table from True to False.

How can I go about doing this without changing any other values?

I am using the code first approach and vehicleID holds the Id of the record I want to edit in the "Vehicles" table

```
var vehicleID = db.RentalAgreements
                  .Where(x => x.rent_agree_no == merchant_reference)
                  .Select(x => x.vehicle_id)
                  .Single();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var d = db.RentalAgreements.Where(x => x.rent_agree_no == merchant_reference).Select(x => x.vehicle_id).Single();

        var vehicle_record = db.Vehicles.FirstOrDefault(p => p.vehicle_id == Convert.ToInt32(d));
        vehicle_record.Availability = false;
        db.SaveChanges();
```